ref counting with map based node objects and pointers
    struct ptr{ 
        const node *ptr; static size_t _c;
    ptr(const node *_ptr = nullptr) : ptr(_ptr) { if(ptr) _c++; }
    ptr(const ptr& rhs) {  ptr = rhs.ptr; if(ptr) _c++;}
    ptr(const ptr&& rhs) {  ptr = rhs.ptr; if(ptr) _c++;}
    inline operator node() const{
        return *ptr;
    }
    inline const node* operator->() const { return ptr;}
    inline ptr& operator=(const ptr& rhs) {
        if(!ptr && rhs.ptr != nullptr ) _c++;
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    inline ptr& operator=(const ptr&& rhs) {     
         if(!ptr && rhs.ptr != nullptr ) _c++;
         ptr = rhs.ptr;
         return *this;
    }
    inline bool operator<(const ptr& rhs) const {
        return ptr < rhs.ptr;
    }
    inline bool operator == (const ptr& rhs) const {
        return ptr == rhs.ptr;
    }
    ~ptr() { 
        if(ptr != nullptr) _c--, ptr = 0 ; 
        if(_c == _mp.size()) _mp.clear();   
    }
    };
       static std::map<node, ptr> _mp; static size_t ptr::nc = 0;

        ptr ptrof(node &pn) { 
            auto r = _mp.emplace( pn, ptr(nullptr) ); 
            if (r.second) r.first->second = ptr(&(r.first->first)); return r.first->second; 
        }

refcounting at the map size granularity, rather individual nodes
using _c to manage when to clear stord node.clear())
This is better than shared_ptr ref counting where ref counter is maintainer per node allocated.
// (here only one )
Above code tries to store pointer to a key in the map as a value against the key in the map.  Also, I added the ptr class that ref counts the node instances in map at the map.size granularity rather individual per node ref counter ( to save overhead of so many ref counters as in shared_ptr design).  I believe this design provides better space saving on ref counter needed. The refcount nc increments when we create pass or copy ptr, either in map or outside external use. The _mp is cleared when there are no external pointers.  THe one issue that I seem not to resolve is that when _mp.clear gets called, it seems to cause seg fault. I believe I captured all _c++ where needed
tried running it but not sure if refcounting is appropriate and map is cleared only when not needed

For a start, that code isn't formatted consistently nor could you compile it. Consider a [mcve] rather than just a snippet. Also, "is appropriate" is very vague. Can you rephrase your question so it becomes clearer? What are your criteria for "appropriate"? What are your doubts?

an actual question would make the question easier to understand. In case you need help to diagnose the segfault you need to show the code that segfaults. Reducing the code is good, but removing so much that it does not have the problem anymore means we cannot tell where the problem is

As far as I'm concerned, it's also quite unclear what that _c is supposed to count. You keep talking about "refcounting", but you can't refcount with a static -- unless you're refcounting a singleton, of course.

if(!ptr && rhs.ptr != nullptr ) _c++; You increement the count when transitioning from null to non-null, but don't decrement the count when transitioning from non-null to null. Did you mean it this way? As in ptr p = &some_node; p = ptr{};

return ptr < rhs.ptr; This generally exhibits undefined behavior. Pointer comparison is only defined between two pointers pointing into the same array. Use std::less{}(ptr, rhs.ptr), it's guaranteed to work on any two pointers.

@ChristianStieber The OP does in effect refcount a singleton - the singleton being static std::map<node, ptr> _mp. The map stores node instances and hands out pointers to those nodes. The idea is that the map can be cleared once there are no longer any pointers to any nodes outstanding.

_mp.clear(); call in the destructor is going to cause trouble. You essentially call size() and clear() again from inside clear() already running, and std::map is probably not prepared to handle reentrant calls. You see, when the last external pointer is destroyed, _c == _mp.size() becomes true and you call clear(). That causes the map to destroy its elements - and for each, ~ptr() destructor is called again, _c == _mp.size() is probably true again, and it calls clear() again, from inside clear() already running.

Well, the clear() does not impact size, unless clear is returned. so any destructors will be invoked in between and these do not see change to size until return from clear @Igor Tandetnik

How do you know? One doesn't normally call size() from inside clear(). For all you know, clear() is emplemented as while (!empty()) erase(begin()); Why don't you print size() inside the destructor and see? Anyway, the standard has this to say: [reentrancy]/1 Except where explicitly specified in this document, it is implementation-defined which functions in the C++ standard library may be recursively reentered.
